# Device specific build settings for "app store release" and "development/debug release"?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am currently developing an app that makes use of the String Augmented Reality SDK demo release ([License Description](http://www.poweredbystring.com/licensing)), and I have merged the SDK with my own code and running on my own iPad (4th Gen).

The weird problem I am having is that whenever I get to the section of the app where the SDK is being used, it complains my app is an app store release and my SDK's license doesn't support it. But I am only testing on my own device and I am not building the app for the app store at all. In fact, I belong to an enterprise license group that does not support app store releases and only for on device testing.

If I use another iOS device (iPad Mini) provisioned with the same profile/license connected to the same computer. The app works completely fine.

Is there a setting either in Xcode build settings or on a specific device itself that states whether an app is for app store release or not?

**UPDATE:** Figured this out, the provisioning profile will need to be imported to both the Xcode resource library and imported specifically to the device itself. The SDK must be checking some special setting where it cannot detect the library provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to sign the debug settings of the target with your development provisioning profile and not your distribution.  One other thing you might try - don't code sign the release settings:

[image]

Comment: My settings are exactly this, developer provisioning profile for debug and "don't code sign" for release. Are there other settings affect whether it's a release build or debug build?

Comment: There are code signing settings for both the target and the project.  Make sure they match.  Aside from that, I don't know of anything else.